# Ionic 2 virtual scroll with masonry cascading grid layout library

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, masonry

I tried this code but not working when i remove `class="gridGallery"`,`class="gridGallery-item"` from code virtual scroll working fine but masonry lib stops working.

**Gallery-custom.html**

```
<ion-list class="gridGallery" [virtualScroll]="itemsss" approxItemHeight="100px">
    <ion-card class="gridGallery-item" *virtualItem="let item">
        <img src={{item.avatarUrl}}>
    </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

**Gallery-custom.ts**

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let elem = document.querySelector('.gridGallery');
        let msnry = new Masonry(elem, {
            itemSelector: '.gridGallery-item',
            columnWidth: '.gridGallery-item',
            gutter: 0,
            fitWidth: true,
            horizontalOrder: false,
            resize: true
          });
          console.log(msnry);
    }, 100);
  }
```

Comment: hi there, did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Not yet, i have used temporary solution called Api for next images on page scroll event. but it's not working smoothly.